# Android ArrayAdapter Filter not updating size leaving empty cells

Tags: android, filtering, android-arrayadapter, notifydatasetchanged

I'm building an Activity with a list of users that gets filtered through a SearchView. I have custom filtering setup and everything is working great on that end.

After the items are filtered, for some reason the adapter still thinks it has all the items to show, so I end up with empty cells.

#### Screenshot of Issue

[image: As you see the cells are filtered but the rest of cells are not removed.]

#### Code for updating list

```java
private void updateView(data) {
    if (customListAdapter == null ) {
        customListAdapter = new ProfilesListViewAdapter(this, R.layout.view_profile_list_cell, data);
        usersListView.setAdapter(customListAdapter);
        //enables filtering for the contents of the given ListView
        usersListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    }
    customListAdapter.setData(data);
}
```

#### Code for ArrayAdapter

```java
public ProfilesListViewAdapter(Context mContext, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList data) {
    super(mContext, layoutResourceId, data);

    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.data = data;
    this.filteredData = data;
}

public void setData(ArrayList data) {
    this.data.clear();
    this.data.addAll(data);
    this.filteredData.clear();
    this.filteredData.addAll(data);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

*NOTE: `data` is used to keep all original information. `filteredData` is the one used in the `getView` method to fill the cells.*

#### Code for ArrayAdapter filtering

```java
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, Filter.FilterResults results) {
            filteredData = (ArrayList<ProfileCellItem>) results.values;
            ProfilesListViewAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            ArrayList<ProfileCellItem> filteredResults = getFilteredResults(constraint);
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            results.values = filteredResults;
            return results;
        }
    };
}

public ArrayList<ProfileCellItem> getFilteredResults(CharSequence constraint) {
    ArrayList<ProfileCellItem> results = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ProfileCellItem cellItem : data) {
        if (cellItem.getName().contains(constraint) ||
            cellItem.getName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint) ||
            cellItem.getSubtitle().contains(constraint) ||
            cellItem.getSubtitle().toLowerCase().contains(constraint)) {
            results.add(cellItem);
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

Comment: You may be sending in data array list with that many row with some empty. Where do you get the data arraylist from when you call `updateView(data)`. Also ArrayList of what? ArrayList<String>? can you post more code how you create the arraylist?

Comment: is it always empty adapter cells at the endof the list? http://android-er.blogspot.com/2014/04/example-of-viewpager-with-custom.html  after you apply your filter, call "destroyItem() " on position Values greater than $filteredSet.size...

Comment: `data` does not have any empty rows in it. It is an `ArrayList` of custom objects of type `ProfileCellItem` as it is clear in the code I provided. I, also, verified that the `filteredData` has only what it needs to have. @Thupten